# Could anyone give me some suggestion about configure secure audit system

Tags: linux, security, configuration, solaris, audit

I'm new about configure audit system. And I have some tasks such as

```
configure audit system to audit failed attempts to access files and programs.
configure audit system to audit files and programs deleted by user...
...
```

I am very confused about the tasks.
Could anyone provided some tutorial or reference links? 
So that I can get clear about what is audit?
How to configure audit system?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How to configure the audit system depends greatly on the software whose audit system you are trying to configure - different software packages have different audit systems, and unless you're writing your own, this seems more like a serverfault.com question than stackoverflow.   In any case, you'll need to give more details to get useful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this is written from the point of view of Solaris, but it still applies to Linux, but some commands and configurations will differ - the general principle is the same though.

The first step is to enable auditing, which is done by running `/etc/security/bsmconv` and answering `y` to the question, and then reboot to load the kernel module which is required for auditing to occur.

Next step is to configure what you should audit, which is done in `/etc/security/audit_control`. There you list what the classes of events which should be audited, and since you haven't provided a complete list, I'll give you a rough estimate of what you might need:

```
flags:lo,ex,fm,fd,ad
naflags:na,lo,ad
```

This will audit login and logout events, executions, file modifications and deletions, and administrative events. The complete list of audit classes can be found in `/etc/security/audit_class`. Which classes should be configured is determined by your company's security policy, so be sure to review it.

Finally tell the audit daemon to load the changes you just made using `audit -s`. This will generate an audit trail in `/var/audit` which can searched sorted using the `auditreduce` command and then be translated into human readable format by the `praudit` command.

You should also configure log rotation (in cron) using `audit -n` to prevent the audit file from becoming too large.

Comment: Martin, thanks a lot for your detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

In this case they are using the word "audit" as the ability to detect this behavior.   I am pretty sure that the only way to detect this behavior is with a kernel module.   There maybe one already written,  but I do not know of one.

Comment: Rook, thanks for your suggestions! I will have a investigation of this.